# Spectroscopic Notation for Atoms and Molecules using chemformula

Tags: chemformula, scientific-notation

I want to write spectroscopic transitions and atomic excited states. For example, N₂⁺(C-B,0-0) and He(2³S).
Currently, I am using chemformula, but the input is very messy, for these examples I need to type: `\ch{N2^+(B-X, "0" {}-{} "0" )}` and `\ch{He( '2' ^3S)`.
I think it would help to turn off the automatic subscription of numbers in compounds and treat them instead like characters. Is there any possibility to do that?
Alternatively, are there other ways more convenient ways to input this? Maybe I did not recognize possibilities...

Cheers,
Niklas

MWE to play:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
desired input: 
\ch{N2^+(B-X,0-0)}

desired output:
\ch{N2^+(B-X, "0" {}-{} "0" )}

desired input:
\ch{He(2^3S)}

desired output:
\ch{He( '2' ^3S)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out some ways by myself.

For the Helium states, I am now using the super- and subscript numbers, without chemformula, like this: He(2³S₁). With LuaLatex, this translates nicely to the corresponding output.
For the nitrogen transitions, I recreated the dashes using pstricks and wrote an own command to typeset them. For me, this is fine.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
desired input: 
\ch{N2^+(B-X,0-0)}

desired output:
\ch{N2^+(B-X, "0" {}-{} "0" )}

Solution: \newcommand{\trans}[2]{#1\psline[linecap=1,linewidth = 0.5pt](0.05em,0.75ex)(0.55em,0.75ex)\hspace{0.6em}#2}
\ch{N2^+}(\trans{B}{X},\trans{0}{0})

desired input:
\ch{He(2^3S)}

desired output:
\ch{He( '2' ^3S)}

Solution:
He(2³S)

\end{document}
```